# android error: no suitable method found - Build failed

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm creating a android webview app and added a class to open internal URL within the app but allow external URLs to use the browser.  I keep getting the error:

> "Error:(21, 26) error: no suitable method found for
>   startActivities(Intent) method
>   Context.startActivities(Intent[],Bundle) is not applicable (actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length) method
>   Context.startActivities(Intent[]) is not applicable (actual argument
>   Intent cannot be converted to Intent[] by method invocation
>   conversion)"

```
package edu.httpsocc.mylakerlinkgo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by 130308 on 11/25/2015.
 */
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("mylakerlink.socc.edu/go")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivities(intent);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a single Intent to a method that expects an array of Intents.  Either pass an array, or call `startActivity`.